# Cross-platform mobile pattern for navigating among, editing, and creating cards

Tags: navigation, mobile-application, mobile-web, cards

I'm a backend dev (mostly), very new to UX. I'm building a mobile-friendly Progressive Web App that allows users to view and edit cards with a few attributes (discussions: title, image, description, time, links, and instructions; [demo](https://civ.dandv.me) if that helps).

I'd like to not reinvent the wheel, but reuse well-established patterns. Such apps have to be common, but none comes to my mind other than dating apps, which only handle viewing cards. I've been reading through [Google's responsive design guidelines](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/design-and-ux/responsive) and [basic mobile navigation patterns](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2017/05/basic-patterns-mobile-navigation/) but haven't found this topic comprehensively addressed.

I'm looking in particular for:

- navigation that's uniform on Android and iOS, especially the 'Back' functionality
- showing previews vs. the full card
- transitioning between viewing and editing a card
- creating a new card

Is there a "model" app for this use case? Or some pattern guidelines for card management?

Comment: What have you come up so far? Can you show us some mock-ups or is that demo by you?

Comment: @locationunknown: yes, the demo is by me.

Answer (score 1):

The link is not available anymore but I think I can refer you to the right place. [Google's material design](https://material.io/components/cards). The principles are universal and can be applied cross-platform (although the iOS enthusiasts will frown at the idea):

**navigation that's uniform on Android and iOS, especially the 'Back' functionality**

**creating a new card**

https://material.io/components/cards#actions

**showing previews vs. the full card**

**transitioning between viewing and editing a card**

https://material.io/components/cards#behavior